# How to use a dispatch (react-redux) into class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

#### My code

```
class LoginPage extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <TextInput/>
          <br/>
          <TextInput/>
          <br/>
          <Button onClick={() => {
            const dispatcher = useDispatch();
            dispatcher(singIn())
          }}>SING IN</Button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

I guess that I am using a hooks in a class component, but what can I use instead of `useDispacth` to my LoginPage?

Comment: thaks for your help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For class components, you need to use `connect` method from `react-redux`. Use connect method and pass `mapDispatchToProps` function as shown below.

```js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
class LoginPage extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <TextInput/>
                <br/>
                <TextInput/>
                <br/>
                <Button onClick={() => {
                    this.props.singIn()
                }}>SING IN</Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}



const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        signIn: () => dispatch(signIn())
    }
};
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginPage)
```

Read thru the doc for more info.
https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect